# Running Passenger 6.0.2 without Nginx?

Tags: nginx, passenger

For an existing rails app I would like to use Passenger without Nginx (because I already use Traefik as reverse-proxy / load balancer).

But passenger start always stats Nginx too. Sadly I'm neither an Passenger nor an Nginx expert.

How can I start passenger "standalone" ?

I'm using

```
Passenger 6.0.2
Rails 5.1.1
```

I'm starting passenger with ...

```
bundle exec passenger start -e production
```

There's no passengerconfig.json (...)
Reading the docs didn't help.

This is how I start the passenger

```
#!/bin/bash
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec passenger start -e production
```

When I check the processes using grep I see

```
nginx: master process /usr/local/bundle/gems/passenger-6.0.2/buildout/support-binaries/nginx-1.15.8 -c /tmp/passenger-standalone.184ibaq/nginx.conf -p /tmp/passenger-standalone.184ibaq
nginx: worker process
root        
/usr/local/bundle/gems/passenger-6.0.2/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent temp-dir-toucher /tmp/passenger-standalone.184ibaq --cleanup --daemonize --pid-file /tmp/passenger-standalone.184ibaq/temp_dir_toucher.pid --log-file /usr/src/app/log/passenger.3000.log --nginx-pid 27
```

Please help me how I can (re-)configure Passenger, so it skips Nginx.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found the solution myself:

```
passenger start -e production --engine=builtin
```

If you know a better solution, please let me know.